# AJAX requests: How can I implement an "else" condition for unhandled HTTP status codes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, switch-statement, http-status-codes

I am trying to react to the HTTP status codes in some AJAX.  I am successful in reacting to specified status codes, but I do not want to have to check for every single one. Is there a way to write an `else` statement in the following code? Or does AJAX not do that?

```
$(function () {
    var url = "google.com";
    $.ajax(url,
            {
                statusCode: {
                    200: function () {
                        //react to status code 200
                    },
                    404: function () {
                        //react to status code 404
                    },
                    503: function () {
                        //react to status code 503
                    }
                    //if neither 200, 404, or 503, then react some way
                }
            });
});
```

I have tried writing `else`, using `,`, using nothing, etc. No success. And I don't think the generic `switch` statement will work with what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why wouldn't a generic switch statement work?

Comment: I'm an ajax newb, but im pretty sure that is specialized syntax to grab an http status code. i could be mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can check the HTTP response code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function()
{
  switch (this.status)
  {
    case 200: console.log("The file exists!"); break;
    case 404: console.log("The file does not exist."); break;
    default:  console.log("Something else happened..."); break;
  }
};
xhr.open("get", "http://localhost:3000/something.png", true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();
```

Comment: thanks, but i am tryinig to be able to specify the page i want the code from.  google.com is the example i am using in the question

Comment: @Evorlor That's what the `xhr.open()` line does. Be aware that you might run into [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues if you try to request stuff from another domain (such as google.com) though.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this:  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   when using your example code.  Don't think that is going to work for me

Comment: I didn't.  After I replaced it with google.com, it gave the expected result.  Thanks!